# How can I create a UIWindow that will delay all events by 200 ms?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow

I'd like to create a custom UIWindow class that will delay all events by 200 ms.
Is it possible? If yes, how?

OK, I created a custom UIApplication class and everything worked fine:

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super sendEvent:event]; NSLog(@"Viola!");
}
```

But once I added this extra code to make it delay the events it didn't send any events.

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(handleEventsAfterDelay:) withObject:event afterDelay:0.500];
}

- (void)handleEventsAfterDelay:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super sendEvent:event]; NSLog(@"Viola!");
}
```

Also, this doesn't work:

```
-(void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:.2]];

    [super sendEvent:event];
}
```

Everything that delays the events doesn't  fire at the end. I'm standing frustrated staring in a blank black screen as the app won't even start.

**EDIT:** I found a way around this problem. Yet, to this day, there's no officially plausible and safe way of doing this but I guess it's just not significant at all.

Comment: All events go through UIApplication, subclass it and pass them to super after 200ms

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think it's a good idea to delay device event. I would try to work around it some how. Also, I'm not sure if Apple will aprove delayed events.

Another reason for me not to try to delay events, is because I'm no guru. I have no idea how the app will start to behave.

That said, as SomeGuy suggested, you could subclass UIApplication and override all event handling methods relevant to your app. Take a look at the [UIApplication class's reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

I've never delayed native events, but I did work with some event manipulation bafore. I remember that back then, overriding `sendEvent:` was enough for what I was doing.

You could override `sendEvent:` as follows:

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.2];
    [super sendEvent:event];
}
```

This will delay **all** event 200 ms. This will however block your main thread.

I've tried to use a call to `dispatch_after(3)` but it didn't work.

If you only want to delay certain event types, use the `UIEvent`'s `type` and `subtype` properties. Take a look at the [UIEvent class's reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Again, I never had to delay, nor do I know what you're exactly trying to accomplish, but I would suggest to find an alternative to delaying the device's event.

Also, don't forget you have to tell Cocoa Touch to use your custom UIApplication. Go to the `main.m` file and add a principal class name to the `UIApplicationMain` call:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([YourApplication class]), NSStringFromClass([YourAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

---

As a reference, this was my overridden method:

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super sendEvent:event];
    // Was it a touch?
    if (event.type == UIEventTypeTouches) {
        // Get touch phase.
        NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
        UITouchPhase phase = [((UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject]) phase];
        // Check what to do.
        switch (phase) {
            case UITouchPhaseBegan:
                // Reset counter.
                [self.counter resetCount];
                break;

            case UITouchPhaseEnded:
            case UITouchPhaseCancelled:
                // Start counter.
                [self.counter startCount];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This was used to auto-sign out users from the app after some inactive time (it was a kiosk app).

Unfortunately, it's the best I can do. Maybe someone with more experience can give their input.

I hope this help.

Comment: Have you tested this?  sendEvent is going to get a lot of invocations, so runUntil will get a lot of overlapping invocations, too.

Comment: I did as you said but I don't know how to delay it properly.

Comment: @danh No, I haven't. And yes, it will probably not work properly. I'm just trying to give a starting point to the user that made the question. I've done a quick edit to be more clear on that. Unfortunately, I don't have time today to make as extensive answer, nor run some tests to make sure I don't write something wrong. If you think you can help, please edit my answer or post on your self ;)

Comment: If you change the delay from .2 to 0 or .0000000000001 it works but that defeats the purpose.

Comment: So basically you're saying "Take @SomeGuy's suggestion and override sendEvent.  Then put some code in there to accomplish your goal.  As a 'starting point' I've added code I know to be incorrect.  Just replace it with the correct code and you're all set".

Comment: I'd be delighted to know what the correct code is sir danh.

Comment: I guess that further in the life of a UIEvent its timestamp plays a crucial role. Delaying a UIEvent by a significant amount like 10 ms will cause it's timestamp to expire that's why if I delay it for 0.00000001 ms then there's no problem. I really need HELP HERE!

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. I don't know if the code works, because I wrote it without testing it. I was busy with work. I've done what I was doing, I'll re-edit the answer shortly after I run some tests.

Comment: @danh I'm sorry if I tried to help and give something user <bignumber> could use as a starting point for their research. I invited you to answer and help and instead you posted a comment I found offensive. If you were/are so mad by my answer you can downvote it, or even flag it. This is quite an obscure topic, I don't know how long this question will be here without a 100% correct answer. I was just trying to help.

Comment: @rtiago42, I re-read all this and see that my tone was too harsh in the "So basically..." comment above.  You're clearly trying to help, and you've put in a bunch of work.  Please accept my apology.

Comment: @danh Thanks, no problem. I've also been too harsh some times. It happens, especially at writing ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem you have is caused by the `UIEvent` timestamp. I suppose that events will expire if it is not delivered within a short interval.

You could try adding `setTimestamp:` by a category and modify it accordingly but the change has to be very exact.